# python SOMETIMES os.environ has no pythonpath

Tags: python, operating-system, sublimetext3, aptana, pythonpath

if i run the following script in Aptana Studio 3:

```
import os
from pprint import pprint
pprint(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep))
```

I get the following output:

```
['C:\\Users\\Phocas_Tommy\\plugins\\org.python.pydev_3.0.0.1388187472\\pysrc\\pydev_sitecustomize',
 'D:\\Phocas\\Phocas-Automation',
 'D:\\Phocas\\Phocas-Automation\\analytics',
 'C:\\Users\\Phocas_Tommy\\plugins\\org.python.pydev_2.7.0.2013032300\\pysrc',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
```

If i run the same script in sublime text 3 i get the this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Phocas\Phocas-Automation\scrapbook.py", line 3, in <module>
    pprint(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 423, in __getitem__
    return self.data[key.upper()]
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
```

Totally confused - Could it be something to do with a project file being read by Aptana, telling the interpreter where to look for the PYTHONPATH? I don't understand why os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] is completely absent when i run it in sublime.

I'm using python 2.7 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Answer (score 1):

PYTHONPATH is an environment variable. How are you starting Sublime Text 3? Why do you think the environment in which it runs should have a PYTHONPATH setting? Can you run Sublime Text from the command line?

The bottom line is that Sublime Text does not appear to be running in the same environment as it is in Aptana Studio.

Comment: This is helpful but i'm still confused - I have some pretty large gaps in my computing knowledge - i can run sublime from the command line if i add to the system path the directory where subl.exe is saved.

I'm not really sure how i configure an environment to have  a PYTHONPATH setting if that makes sense.

Incidentally if i run "python [myscript]" in the command line or in bash, i get the same error. Do i need to add my own system environment variable called PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Well it looks like Aptana is setting `PYTHONPATH`. [This article](https://djangounchain.wordpress.com/2012/12/27/tutorial-2-installing-and-getting-started-with-pydev/) might shed some light on that. Aptana is a complete environment, so I am unsure whether it would take any notice of a `PYTHONPATH` setting that you made in your own environment.